# mod rewrite - have nice urls but still build menu dynamically from database

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am creating my menu dynamically from a database. I started by appending an id to the urls which I used to identify the page in the database and then get all urls from the subpages and so on..

so I had a lot of ids like this `www.page.com/somefolder/pagename.php?id=10`, where 10 is the id of the page and is the parent_id for a number of other pages.

Now I use mod rewrite to get nicer urls. So the above url is now `www.page.com/pagename.php` , which is mapped to the original url.
My pagenames are all gonna be unique.

The question: Do I have to do this for each and every url, since each url needs an id as query string or is there a better way to combine mod rewrite with dynamically generating a menu?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, not for every URL, but you will need to do this the other way around.

Turn the rewrite engine on

```
RewriteEngine on
```

Build a path to match against using a dynamic 'case' in brackets..

```
RewriteRule ^/?somefolder/page/([0-9]+)/?$
```

.. complete the rule with the rewritten URL, using $1 for the 'case'

```
/somefolder/pagename.php?id=$1 [L]
```

Put it all together using [L] to signify the 'last' rule to execute.

```
RewriteRule ^/?somefolder/page/([0-9]+)/?$ /somefolder/pagename.php?id=$1 [NC,L]
```

This will rewrite `/somefolder/page/12345/` to `/somefolder/pagename.php?id=12345`

Comment: Ahh, I see! Thanks a lot!!